# How do we avoid (welcome?) link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks

For example, below post has 2 answers that are *almost* link-only-answers **^1** .

[Improve a reference genome with sequencing data](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/97/131) **^2**

Maybe it is OK? Or would questions asking for a tool should simply be closed? On the other hand, bioinformatics tools/methods are not easy to find. Even if we find them, we are not sure how "good" they are.

**^1:** There is already a good discussion about this at [main SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231).
**^2:** Please read this before upvoting/downvoting: [What is the "meta effect"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Answer (score 4):

I think we should educate our selfs about how and what to ask here and how to answer. SE Meta is the site where questions about how does Stack Exchange sites (like this one and all the others) are asked and answered. To this regard, your link in [main SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/247279) clearly says:

> When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.

So we should:

1. Edit to include the relevant information in the answer if it is already posted.
2. Avoid answering with just a link to where the answer can be find.

On the other hand we should also avoid not crediting the source of our knowledge.

Comment: [Also relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/208518)